# Opencart change modification

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I have already installed modification with xml in Opencart 2.3.0.2
At the beginning the modification was not working properly so I contacted the company that I bought it from and they fixed it. They used another xml file and uploaded it to my system as a modification. Now I want to make a little edit on this thing. The problem is if I edit the current xml which I have it will not work because as I said they uploaded their own xml file so if I upload my own again I will have the problem which I had before they fixed it. Is there any way I can get or edit already installed modification in Opencart ?

Comment: Why don't you just edit *their* XML file?  It's probably in `vqmod/xml`.

Comment: where can I find this vqmod folder ?

Comment: It's at the top level of your cart directory.  Same place as "admin".

Comment: I dont have such folder

Comment: OK, then where ever they put their XML, grab that and update it - don't use your own copy, which is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the "Modification" files in the following path: `siteroot\system\storage\modification`

Comment: I already found what I needed
The files are not stored in the filsystem but as rows in the db in table called oc_modification